# How can i have a div stuck on the left side of the page no matter how much i scroll horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is kind of difficult to explain so ill link to a page that has the effect i need;

http://wpaoli.building58.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/feedback-panel.html

The feedback thing on the left side is what im trying to implement on my side,
instead of feedback im going to use it as a navigation menu that shows up when clicked on.

the things above is what i have right now.

my problem is when i scroll to the right ( my page is around 6000px wide )
i want it to stay on the left side,
is there a way to pull this off?

(this is to much for my brain to handle)..thanks!

Comment: I implemented this a while ago.  You specify the CSS position of the div. I can't recall if it is "relative" or "absolute" that you want.  I woudl try absolute

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the div to have a "position:fixed" style and then set "left:0px;top:0px". This makes the div stick to the top left of the browser instead of its relative position within the HTML flow.

Have a look at this example page, it has 2 fixed elements, one at the top left and the other at the bottom right:

[Fixed example](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html)

Comment: Thank you very much!

I haven't learned what the position attributes does, i just try them out and see which works best sometimes. I think i need to read a little about them

Comment: @David Murdoch, yes you're right, I should have mentioned there are some issues in IE6 but the article I linked to explains this as well as a complete solution for cross browser compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exact same design, only use `position:fixed` on the `feedback-panel`.